# How to reduce swf filesize flex

Tags: optimization, flex3, flash, filesize, reduce

how can i reduce the file size of my flex application. its around 900kb .

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634293/flash-app-depends-on-flex-are-there-any-swf-bytecode-size-optimizers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by implementing rsl on your flex project and splitting it into modules, for details to implement file size optimization.

Check this article: [Optimize Flex SWF filesize performance loading](https://web.archive.org/web/20140723200345/http://askmeflash.com/article/9/optimize-flex-swf-filesize-performance-loading)

Answer (score 0):

An easy to implement solution that article fails to mention is to use a tool to minify your as3 code as part of the deployment compilation process.

In projects with lots of code and few images I've seen this cut the file size by more than  half. There are several open source and $ source kits that do this I've found SecureSWF the most reliable.